# Finding the order of the ideal class group

Tags: number-theory, ideal-class-group

This is an understanding question : to search for the order $n$ of the ideal class group, why do we only need to try to split the $(p)$ where p is a prime $\leq M$ ($M$ being the Minkowski bound) ? I think it's because every ideal class contains an ideal of norm $\leq M$ and that every ideal can be split in a product of primes, and for every ideal $I$, $I^n$ is principal but i can't put it together properly.

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Any ideal class may be represented by a ideal $I$ of norm $\leq M$.

In particular,  any prime ideal $P$ dividing $I$ has norm $\leq M$.
Hence the ideal $I$ is the product of prime ideals with norm $\leq M$.

Note that any prime ideal $P$ is lying above a prime number $p$.  The norm of $P$ is a non trivial power of $p$, so $p\leq M$

So the classes of prime ideals with lying above a prime $p\leq M$ generate the class group.

Now if $p$ is inert, then $P=(p)$ is principal, and its class is trivial in the class group. SO, you just need to consider the non inert $p$.

This is all you can say if you work with an arbitrary number field.

**If you are only interested in quadratic fields**, it is true that you can stick to split  **or totally ramified** primes, because in this case $p$ is inert, split or totally ramified.

However, there are cases where the unique prime ideal lying above a ramified prime is not principal (so a priori you need to take it into account in the class group)

For example, for $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-30})$, $M\approx 6.97$, so you can only consider $p=2,3,5$. All of them are totally ramified, and you can show that the class group is the Klein group, and generated by the classes of $\mathfrak{p}_2$ and $\mathfrak{p}_3$ (see https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/gradnumthy/classgpex.pdf, Example 4).

So you **cannot** only stick to **split** $p\leq M$.

Comment: I think you're misreading the OP's sense of the term "split" when the OP writes "try to split the $(p)$" and "can be split in a product": the OP appears to mean "factor" when writing "split". There appears to be no intention to refer to the technical meaning of rational primes "splitting completely" in a number field.

Comment: Thank you very much ! i think i finally understand thanks to you